# Flutter iOS app has extra ordinary padding from top and bottom / displays inside a box

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-ios

[image]
When I run my flutter app for in iOS (both emulator and physical device), the app is displayed with huge padding from top and bottom. This only happens in iOS, the same app for android runs fine with the normal usual layout. All the app here is limited to  this area in the display. I didn't define any padding for app in the code. What is the reason for this?

Here's the code in relevant screen;

```html
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter_svg/flutter_svg.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/screens/register_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/screens/signup_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/utils/global_variable.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/widgets/post_card.dart';

class FeedScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  const FeedScreen({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<FeedScreen> createState() => _FeedScreenState();
}

class _FeedScreenState extends State<FeedScreen> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final width = MediaQuery.of(context).size.width;

    return Scaffold(
      backgroundColor:
          width > webScreenSize ? webBackgroundColor : mobileBackgroundColor,
      appBar: width > webScreenSize
          ? null
          : AppBar(
              backgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
              centerTitle: false,
              title: Text("Iron Capital"),
              /*SvgPicture.asset(
                'assets/ic_instagram.svg',
                color: primaryColor,
                height: 32,
              ),*/
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(
                    Icons.person_add_alt_1_sharp,
                    color: primaryColor,
                  ),
                  onPressed: () {
                    Navigator.of(context).push(
                      MaterialPageRoute(
                        builder: (context) => const RegisterScreen(),
                      ),
                    );
                  },
                ),
              ],
            ),
      body: StreamBuilder(
        stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance.collection('posts').snapshots(),
        builder: (context,
            AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot<Map<String, dynamic>>> snapshot) {
          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
            return const Center(
              child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
            );
          }
          return ListView.builder(
            itemCount: snapshot.data!.docs.length,
            itemBuilder: (ctx, index) => Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: width > webScreenSize ? width * 0.3 : 0,
                vertical: width > webScreenSize ? 15 : 0,
              ),
              child: PostCard(
                snap: snapshot.data!.docs[index].data(),
              ),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

here's the main.dart file;

```html
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/providers/user_provider.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/responsive/mobile_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/responsive/responsive_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/responsive/web_screen_layout.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/screens/login_screen.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/utils/colors.dart';
import 'package:provider/provider.dart';
import 'package:instagram_clone_flutter/models/user.dart' as model;

import 'resources/auth_methods.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  // initialise app based on platform- web or mobile
  if (kIsWeb) {
    await Firebase.initializeApp(
  /*    options: const FirebaseOptions(
        apiKey: "AIzaSyCZ-xrXqD5D19Snauto-Fx_nLD7PLrBXGM",
        appId: "1:585119731880:web:eca6e4b3c42a755cee329d",
        messagingSenderId: "914283146786",
        projectId: "instagram-clone-4cea4",
        storageBucket: 'instagram-clone-4cea4.appspot.com'
      ),*/
    );
  } else {
    await Firebase.initializeApp();
  }
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<MyApp> createState() => _MyAppState();
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MultiProvider(
      providers: [
        ChangeNotifierProvider(create: (_) => UserProvider(),),
      ],
      child: MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        title: 'Iron Capital',
        theme: ThemeData.dark().copyWith(
          scaffoldBackgroundColor: mobileBackgroundColor,
        ),
        home: StreamBuilder(
          stream: FirebaseAuth.instance.authStateChanges(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.active) {
              // Checking if the snapshot has any data or not
              if (snapshot.hasData) {
              //  final model.User user = Provider.of<UserProvider>(context).getUser;
                 //AuthMethods().signOut();
                /*if(user.nft!.length < 2 ){
                 // await AuthMethods().signOut();
                }*/
                // if snapshot has data which means user is logged in then we check the width of screen and accordingly display the screen layout
                return const ResponsiveLayout(
                  mobileScreenLayout: MobileScreenLayout(),
                  webScreenLayout: WebScreenLayout(),
                );
              } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
                return Center(
                  child: Text('${snapshot.error}'),
                );
              }
            }

            // means connection to future hasnt been made yet
            if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.waiting) {
              return const Center(
                child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
              );
            }

            return const LoginScreen();
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: can you show us the code? also

Comment: can but which part do you need to see? btw app works fine on android, there are no platform-specific code in the project.

Comment: whole code if prefer haha the thing which this page indicate with the codes

Comment: hmm wait a bit cant understand some of it but does this the one showing when if its mobile? this one ? MobileScreenLayout()